# libpqxx configure cannot find libpq-fe.h for local install of PostgreSQL

Tags: bash, postgresql, libpqxx

I'm in the process of generating a build script on a compute cluster running Red Hat 6.6 Linux with restricted `sudo` access. Presently I've been creating a local install of PostgreSQL 10.10, from the sources on GitHub. Following the build they are installed at `/storage/home/work/build_env/postgres` and the `$PATH` is updated so that `pg_config` runs and `pkg-config libpq --cflags` returns

```
-I/storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/include
```

libpqxx is being cloned from the GitHub source, but is getting stuck at configuration with the following error:

```
configure: using PostgreSQL headers at /storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/include
configure: using PostgreSQL libraries at /storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/lib
checking /storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/include  /libpq-fe.h usability... no
checking /storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/include  /libpq-fe.h presence... no
checking for /storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/include  /libpq-fe.h... no
configure: error:
Can't find libpq-fe.h in /storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/include  .  Are you sure the libpq
headers are installed correctly?  They should be in the directory returned by
"pg_config --includedir" or "pkg-config libpq --cflags".

If you do have libpq (the C-language client library for PostgreSQL) installed,
make sure you have the related development materials--mainly its header files--
as well as the library binary.  Some system distributions keep the two in
seperate packages with names like "alibrary" and "alibrary-dev", respectively.
In that case, make sure you have the latter installed as well.
```

However, looking in the directory that `pkg-config` returns I see the following:

```
[user@compute libpqxx]$ ls -al /storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/include | grep libpq
drwxrws---  2 user user_collab  4096 Nov  7 13:35 libpq
-rw-r--r--  1 user user_collab  2211 Nov  7 13:35 libpq-events.h
-rw-r--r--  1 user user_collab 22179 Nov  7 13:35 libpq-fe.h
```

What could be causing this issue with the file not being found by the configuration script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

The error is actually quite obvious from the logs, but subtle as well. As noted in the question, the file exists at the correct path; however, the script has superfluous white-space in it:

```
/storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/include  /libpq-fe.h
```

when it should be:

```
/storage/home/work/build_env/postgres/include/libpq-fe.h
```

This is correctable by stripping the whitespace using `sed` using the pattern `sed 's/ *$//g'`. This can be done by updating the configure script *in situ*:

```
19006 -  with_postgres_include=$($PKG_CONFIG libpq --cflags | sed 's/^-I//')
19006 +  with_postgres_include=$($PKG_CONFIG libpq --cflags | sed 's/^-I//' | sed 's/ *$//g')
```

This issue has been [addressed in the libpqxx repository](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/commit/1e37f1ee9b163097b129186221ce0e9afb96a997), so the canonical solution would be to upgrade to the latest version of the source code if the problem is encountered.